# How to fix ‘ImportError: cannot import name 'QtScript' from 'PySide2' error in PySide2

Tags: python, pyside2

I couldn't import QtScript in PySide2. I don't understand why and how to do it. Here's demo code in PySide2 examples file.

I could import QtWidgets, QtCore and more.

```
"""PySide2 port of the script/helloscript example from Qt v5.x"""

import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtScript
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#app = QApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

engine = QtScript.QScriptEngine()

button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
scriptButton = engine.newQObject(button)
engine.globalObject().setProperty("button", scriptButton)

engine.evaluate("button.text = 'Hello World from PySide2!'")
engine.evaluate("button.styleSheet = 'font-style: italic'")
engine.evaluate("button.show()")

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
> ImportError: cannot import name 'QtScript' from 'PySide2'
> (C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PySide2\__init__.py)

In the "__init__.py",the first port is like this.

    __all__ = list("Qt" + body for body in
        "Core;Gui;Widgets;PrintSupport;Sql;Network;Test;Concurrent;WinExtras;Xml;XmlPatterns;Help;Multimedia;MultimediaWidgets;OpenGL;Positioning;Location;Qml;Quick;QuickWidgets;RemoteObjects;Scxml;Sensors;TextToSpeech;Charts;Svg;DataVisualization;UiTools;AxContainer;WebChannel;WebEngineCore;WebEngine;WebEngineWidgets;WebSockets;3DCore;3DRender;3DInput;3DLogic;3DAnimation;3DExtras"
        .split(";"))
```

Comment: According to [this ticket](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-707), QtScript was deprecated in Qt 5.5 and they mentioned they'll update the README. There is also something about how it isn't there in the wheel, but can be obtained by building from scratch. Did you install from the wheel?

Comment: I just forgot to explain my version. The version is  "5.12.3"

Comment: I have installed it compiling the source code (and in my version of Qt I have QtScript compiled) and I can use QtScript so it seems that the compiled version provided by Qt for Python does not have it.

Comment: So I think that if you want to use a module deprecated as QtScript you must compile Qt manually, and the same for PySide2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just thought some reason in my installing process. Maybe I need to install it from source

Comment: You need to compile Qt by enabling QtScript, and then use that Qt to compile PySide2.  If you do not have experience compiling Qt it can be a headache. Bye

Comment: haha, maybe it would be a problem. But it's easy to find some solution.Thanks